# ESP32: Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (StoreProhibited) in GY521 I2C project

Tags: esp32, i2c, gy-521

Good afternoon, I hope you are well.

I'm new here on SO, I apologize in advance for my English.

I'm doing a project with 4 accelerometers and a TCA9548A multiplexer to talk to an esp32. The samples of the 4 sensors are correct, but this error appears "ESP32: Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (StoreProhibited)" at the beginning of each sample, and I would like to know what I could modify in the code to resolve this error.

```
#include <Adafruit_MPU6050.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Wire.h>

Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu1;
Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu2;
Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu3;
Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu4;
unsigned long _time;

void TCA9548A(uint8_t bus){
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);  // TCA9548A address
  Wire.write(1 << bus);          // send byte to select bus
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void printValues(Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu, int bus) {
  sensors_event_t a, g, temp;
  mpu.getEvent(&a, &g, &temp);
  TCA9548A (bus);
  Serial.print("Sensor: ");
  Serial.println(bus);
  Serial.print("Eixo X:");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.x);
  Serial.print(" m/s^2, ");
  Serial.print("\tEixo Y:");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.y);
  Serial.print(" m/s^2, ");
  Serial.print("\tEixo Z:");
  Serial.print(a.acceleration.z);
  Serial.print(" m/s^2,");
  Serial.print("\t Temperatura: ");
  Serial.print(temp.temperature);
  Serial.println(" °C");
}

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();

  TCA9548A(2);
  if (!mpu1.begin(0x68)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor on bus 2, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println();
  
  // Init sensor on bus number 3
  TCA9548A(3);
  if (!mpu2.begin(0x68)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor on bus 3, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println();
  
  // Init sensor on bus number 4
  TCA9548A(4);
  if (!mpu3.begin(0x68)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor on bus 4, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println();
  
  // Init sensor on bus number 5
  TCA9548A(5);
  if (!mpu4.begin(0x68)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor on bus 5, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  printValues(mpu1, 2);
  printValues(mpu2, 3);
  printValues(mpu3, 4);
  printValues(mpu4, 5);
  yield();
  delay(100);
  }
```

On the serial monitor I get the following result

```
Sensor: 2
Eixo X:-0.72 m/s^2, Eixo Y:-0.03 m/s^2,     Eixo Z:9.71 m/s^2,   Temperatura: 26.84 °C
Sensor: 3
Eixo X:0.36 m/s^2,  Eixo Y:-0.27 m/s^2,     Eixo Z:8.31 m/s^2,   Temperatura: 24.62 °C
Sensor: 4
Eixo X:0.16 m/s^2,  Eixo Y:-0.19 m/s^2,     Eixo Z:9.86 m/s^2,   Temperatura: 27.26 °C
Sensor: 5
Eixo X:0.71 m/s^2,  Eixo Y:0.10 m/s^2,  Eixo Z:9.82 m/s^2,   Temperatura: 27.02 °C
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (StoreProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400ebac0  PS      : 0x00060130  A0      : 0x800d19a2  A1      : 0x3ffb1db0  
A2      : 0x00010001  A3      : 0x000000ae  A4      : 0x00060023  A5      : 0x3ffb8058  
A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x00000000  A8      : 0x00010101  A9      : 0x00000001  
A10     : 0x3ffc02ac  A11     : 0x3ffc0110  A12     : 0x00000020  A13     : 0x80000020  
A14     : 0x00000008  A15     : 0x00000001  SAR     : 0x0000000a  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001d  
EXCVADDR: 0x00010127  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x400ebac0:0x3ffb1db0 0x400d199f:0x3ffb1dd0 0x400d1a6a:0x3ffb1df0 0x400d1819:0x3ffb1e10 0x400d1492:0x3ffb1e40 0x400d16e2:0x3ffb1e90 0x400d0e99:0x3ffb1eb0 0x400d0f5e:0x3ffb1f40 0x400d3999:0x3ffb1fb0 0x400869bd:0x3ffb1fd0

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:10124
load:0x40080400,len:5856
entry 0x400806a8
```

I went to the board manager and updated esp32, then when compiling the algorithm the following error appeared:

```
CORRUPT HEAP: Bad head at 0x3ffb94ec. Expected 0xabba1234 got 0x3ffb8014

assert failed: multi_heap_free multi_heap_poisoning.c:253 (head != NULL)


Backtrace:0x400837b9:0x3ffb25800x40088135:0x3ffb25a0 0x4008d001:0x3ffb25c0 0x4008cc67:0x3ffb26f0 0x40083ae9:0x3ffb2710 0x4008d031:0x3ffb2730 0x400e1d41:0x3ffb2750 0x400d1591:0x3ffb2770 0x400d1697:0x3ffb2790 0x400d143e:0x3ffb27b0 0x400d3e19:0x3ffb2820 




ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x17 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
load:0x40078000,len:13160
load:0x40080400,len:3036
entry 0x400805e4
```

when running the tool, I got the following result:

```
Decoding stack results
0x400837b9: panic_abort at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_system/panic.c line 402
0x40088135: esp_system_abort at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_system/esp_system.c line 128
0x4008d001: __assert_func at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/newlib/assert.c line 85
0x4008cc67: multi_heap_free at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/heap/multi_heap_poisoning.c line 245
0x40083ae9: heap_caps_free at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/heap/heap_caps.c line 340
0x4008d031: free at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/newlib/heap.c line 39
0x400e1d41: operator delete(void*) at /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/HOST-i686-w64-mingw32/xtensa-esp32-elf/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/del_op.cc line 49
0x400d1591: Adafruit_MPU6050_Temp::~Adafruit_MPU6050_Temp() at C:\Users\thiag\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_Sensor-master/Adafruit_Sensor.h line 165
0x400d1697: Adafruit_MPU6050::~Adafruit_MPU6050() at C:\Users\thiag\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_MPU6050\Adafruit_MPU6050.cpp line 50
0x400d143e: loop() at C:\Users\thiag\Desktop\Trabalho/Trabalho.ino line 74
0x400d3e19: loopTask(void*) at C:\Users\thiag\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.5\cores\esp32\main.cpp line 50
```

Comment: If you are using Arduino IDE, install [Exception Stack Trace Decoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) to your IDE first, copy and paste the Guru Panic backtrace to see what caused it? If you still can't figure it out, update your post with the decoded trace, we will see what we can help.

Comment: You are passing the entire copy of the mpu object every time you call the `printValues()` function on each loop, I suspect that somehow cause it to run out of memory. You should try to pass the pointer of an mpu object `printValues(Adafruit_MPU6050 *mpu, int bus)` or `printValues(int bus)` and use the bus value to determine which mpu object should be called within the function with a `switch..case` statement.

Comment: Don't post error msg in comment, edit your post and add an "update" section there with your trace. You said you updated the esp32 file, what did you updated, you code need to be in line with the trace.

Comment: I'm sorry, I update the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> void printValues(Adafruit_MPU6050 mpu, int bus)

When you passing in an argument to a function, the function create a copy of whatever you are passing in as the parameter, in your code, you are passing an entire instance of `Adafruit_MPU6050` object, which is big. What you should do is to change your code to pass in the pointer to the object (which is only 16-bit in Arduino) to the function.

```cpp
void printValues(Adafruit_MPU6050* mpu, int bus) {  // passing pointer of mpu object
  TCA9548A (bus);
  sensors_event_t a, g, temp;
  mpu->getEvent(&a, &g, &temp);  // using pointer notation
  // rest of your code
}
```

I don't have the same hardware configuration as yours to test this code, you need to try and test it to confirm if this is working.